# Firefox Web Developer Toolbar: JS does not work after an "on the fly" HTML edit

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, web-developer-toolbar

I'm getting used to this toolbar, it is so cool to edit the page on the fly and see what I'm changing...

THe only problem is that my JavaScript stops to work after (or while) i'm editing, and I need to save an refresh the page... Did I miss any option? Is there any other tool that does this?

Answer (score 1):

[Firebug.](http://getfirebug.com/) I almost never use Web Developer anymore. (resizing feature is nice though)

Comment: Same thing, Try even here on stackoverflow to change the text "add comment" with something else and then click on  it, it loses the effect.

Comment: Got it, I wonder if it's readding the element or something along those lines. If that's what it's doing, and I imagine that's the case, then there's really no solution except rebinding the event to the element.

Answer (score 0):

You wont be able to see the changes unless you save and refresh. So Save and Refresh seems Ok to me. Can you tell us examples of what happens?

Comment: I see the changes in "real time" without saving, i.e. I change the text in a div... but while (and after) i'm doing this JS events/effects do not work (onclicks, rollovers...)